# Import Excel file with splitted cell

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, xlsx

How I can import splited cell from an Excel table into a DataTable?

[image]

Comment: What are you using for importing from Excel?

Comment: There is no such thing as a splitted cell. There are only merged cells.

Answer (score 0):

I would use library EPPlus.

You can download it here:
http://epplus.codeplex.com/

then you can unmerge them and read as written in this:
[How to un-merge cells EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766973/how-to-un-merge-cells-epplus)

Comment: How does this answer the question? Even as a comment, this looks rather poor to me.

Comment: The question is somehow blurry, we don't know what Shani already tried and what is his exact problem. So i give some way to go, if he is still in the beginning.